# Lose contact with resources - why

Tags: java, android

Im developing in eclipse with 5 activities, but suddenly I loose contact with all my resources.

Have anyone experienced this phenomenon and knows what to do about it? I have already tried cleaning up the project but no luck

Update:
I managed to resolve the issues by deleting the project and then importing an older version, which worked. Then copying and pasting from the new and damaged version to the old version..

Comment: What do you mean with "loose contact"?

Comment: I cannot reference them anymore. :S I have checked the R.java file and everything is there

Comment: When I look at the navigation tree (package explorer) only the first activity.java file's icon has a red cross on it symbolising errors (all resource errors). The intellisence for referencing resources does not work in this file, but it works in the remaining files.. I have tried removing this first activity.java file from the project, but then the "pattern" is the same with the new top java class in the package explorer

Comment: I had a nightmare with `R.java` once and had to do a lot of voodoo incantations of deleting it, removing `import R`, complete clean+rebuild: several times in random orders.  I'm not sure if you're having the same problem though.

Comment: Occasionally I'm having some trouble with the R file not being generated properly, but project clean usually fixes that in my case. Did you try restarting Eclipse? Are the used resources still present in your project's `res` folder and still readable?

Comment: Also check if there are there any other (non resource related) errors in your activity and fix these errors first.

Comment: OMG I hope not - Hearing you saying this makes me uncomfortable

Answer (score 2):

Check your recently edited resources for errors (e.g. malformed XML in a layout file you just changed). If there is one error, the whole resource generation will be stopped and you can't reference anything.

Comment: I can't seem to find any errors.. I have checked manually the Strings.xml including some menu xml

Comment: Does the console [Window->Show View->Console] in eclipse mention anything (e.g. "Error in an XML file: aborting build.")?

Comment: It has two entries stating that: [2011-07-21 14:56:05 - SDK Manager] Warning: Ignoring platform 'android-12': build.prop is missing.

Comment: Mh thats definitely not normal. But I dont know how to fix this. Edit this into your question, so people who skip by here see it (they may not read all the comments). Edit: Don't panic, this sounds like a setup issue with the SDK or project settings. Should be fixable some way.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this issue before.

- Close your project
- open once again
- Refresh it
- Check whether android jar is missing in javaBuild path if yes then
  set that path to the android sdk location in your device.
- then refresh the project.

Thanks

Comment: Where can I find this build path?

Comment: right click on your project. select properties then in the left corner you can find some options there BuildPath is one of them.

Comment: I dont have any jar files here. In Source tab I have: ProjectName/gen and ProjectName/src. The projects tab is empty. The Libraries tab has one entry named Android 2.3.3 and the Order and Export tab has three entries: ProjectName/src, ProjectName/gen and Android 2.3.3 (the first two are checked)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced it a couple of times myself.

Try to refresh and refresh and refresh again.

Some other tips is to go through all your xml files (the ones you have created yourself) and manually see if they contain errors. Eclipse may not always show which specific file which has the error and therefore you need to browse through them yourself.

Another thing could be the naming of your files. Make sure they are named properly. Incorrect (illegal) names may not always be recognized properly.